# How can I configure Visual Studio Code to run/debug .NET (dotnet) Core from the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed .NET Core 2.2 in the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) and created a new project. I've also installed the C# extension for Visual Studio Code and the syntax highlighting and IntelliSense seems to be working.

However, when I try to use the debugger, things stop working. Here's a step by step of what I've tried to do to configure it.

Here's my *launch.json* file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CodeCore.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/CodeCore.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my *tasks.json* file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

My directory structure:

[image]

But when I click the "Start Debugging" button I get the following error:

> launch: program " does not exist

Comment: You have comments INSIDE your json, this is usually not a great idea. Can you remove those and try?

Comment: Oh sure I can so that but those were added by VS Code which generated the base for those json files. I am skeptical it will make a difference.

Answer (score 7):

There is a great article on GitHub regarding the subject - [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux).

To cut a long story short, you need to first verify your version after the Windows 10 [Creators Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_1703):

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release  | grep  -i version
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
```

**Notice the following**:

> If you had upgraded to Windows Creators update and already had WSL
> installed, you might still have Ubuntu 14 in the WSL. If the version
> is 14, run the following commands in a cmd prompt to reinstall and
> update WSL.

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
lxrun /install
```

**Download the debugger**:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
```

The debugger will be installed at `~/vsdbg/vsdbg`. It is the *debuggerPath*.

**Sample launch.json configuration for launch**:

```
  {
           "name": ".NET Core WSL Launch",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "launch",
           "preLaunchTask": "publish",
           "program": "/mnt/c/temp/dotnetapps/wslApp/bin/publish/wslApp.dll",
           "args": [],
           "cwd": "/mnt/c/temp/dotnetapps/wslApp",
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "console": "internalConsole",
           "pipeTransport": {
               "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
               "pipeProgram": "bash.exe",
               "pipeArgs": [ "-c" ],
               "debuggerPath": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg"
           }
       }
```

Please note:

- /.vscode/launch.json: This provides an array of different configurations you can use to launch your application. There is a drop down in the Debug view for selecting which configuration is active.
- *<your-open-folder>/.vscode/tasks.json*: This provides an array of different tasks, like building your application, that you can execute. Debug configurations can link to one of these tasks through the preLaunchTask property.

**Sample 'publish' task for** *tasks.json* **(needed for launching)**:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        ...,
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/wslApp.csproj",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/bin/publish"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Please Note**:

- preLaunchTask executes `dotnet publish`, which builds the project on Windows. Since coreclr is cross-platform, the binary can be executed on WSL without any extra work.
- pipeProgram is set to *bash.exe*.
- debuggerPath points to vsdbg, the coreclr debugger.
- This will not support programs that want to read from the console.

**Sample launch.json configuration for attach**:

```
 {
           "name": ".NET Core WSL Attach",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "attach",
           "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
           "pipeTransport": {
               "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
               "pipeProgram": "bash.exe",
               "pipeArgs": [ "-c" ],
               "debuggerPath": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg",
               "quoteArgs": true
           }
       }
```

**Please Note**:

- `"processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}"` lists the processes running on WSL using the pipe program.
- `quoteArgs` will quote any arguments and debugger commands with spaces if set to true.
- Use `sourceFileMap` to map sources if they are available in a
  different location than where they were built. If you build your
  project in Linux, make sure to add a map from the `/mnt` drive
  letters. Example: `"sourceFileMap": { "/mnt/c/": "c:\\" }`
- File and paths are case sensitive in Linux.

Comment: `lxrun.exe` isn't available in latest windows 10 releases. Use `wslconfig.exe /uninstall distro-name`.

Comment: Great help thanks, is there a way to get rid of the hardcoded `/mnt/c/temp/dotnetapps/wslApp` and replace that with a variable or custom vscode command?